# 19.10: How to passthrough Dolby DTS/AC3 from Kodi

Tags: sound, ac3

I'm trying to get passthrough audio on my receiver from [Kodi](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux) on Ubuntu. I can only assume the Dolby codecs aren't installed by default as everything worked fine in Windows 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 19.10 sorry, revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to ALSA as audio device for Kodi. See https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=343813